# Can't debug stored procedures in Visual Studio. 'Step Into Stored Procedure' is missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I created a test WinForms app in Visual Studio 2013 Premium (admin) & Update2. Enabled SQL Server debugging. Created a data connection to my local Northwind database. I am admin on the box. Expanded the stored procedures list and right clicked on several SP's and I was expecting a 'step into Stored Procedure' option and it doesn't exist. I am following the steps from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316549).

I right clicked on the connection name and there's no enable SQL/CLR debugging option. I read about references to SQL Server Object Explorer which is under Server Explorer and that's missing too. I am using SQL Server 2012 Developer edition.

Why am I missing all these options?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might need to install SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027